# Javascript prevent decrement past 0

Tags: javascript

Probably a rookie question, but how do I prevent the decrement from going past zero into the negative numbers?

```
public counter : number = 0;
increment(){
  this.counter += 1;
}

decrement(){
  this.counter -= 1;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: Is this TypeScript?

Comment: there is no way to prevent decrement (`--`) or subtraction assignment (`-=`) from going below 0. Apply logic to determine whether or not you need to modify the value in first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply check if the counter is still greater than zero and only if so you actually decrement your counter

```
decrement(){
  if(this.counter > 0){
    this.counter -= 1
  }
}
```

Comment: what if it's 0.5?

Comment: @Max You're totally right, this would break if counter will not be an integer. But according to the question i think we can assume that counter will only be changed by increment and decrement methods which results in counter being an integer.

Comment: It won't be an integer - so this worked perfectly.  I probably should have clarified that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

For clarity, I suggest to use the [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) function to make sure that the value is always greater than or equal to `0`.

```
decrement(){
  this.counter = Math.max(0, this.counter - 1);
}
```

This is not the fastest way to do this but as long as you don't call `decrement()` in a loop for several hundred thousand times, the performance degradation is too small to be perceived.

Answer (score 1):

Write the function to clamp it at zero:

```
decrement(){
  this.counter -= 1;
  if (this.counter < 0) {
     this.counter = 0;
  end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using ternary operator too.

```js
value > 0 ? value - 1 : 0
```